# Error Installing Jekyll in Cygwin

Tags: ruby, cygwin, jekyll

So I attempted to install Jekyll on Windows through Cygwin and I encountered an error when I tried to install Jekyll through Cygwin. Here is the output.

```
Michael@X556UAK: ~$ gem install jekyll
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /c/Users/Michael/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20171011-7692-lgoixq.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/share/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /c/Users/Michael/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ffi-   1.9.18 for inspection.
Results logged to /c/Users/Michael/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-cygwin/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.18/gem_make.out
```

I conducted some research online and I wasn't able to find a solution. I tried running Cygwin as an administrator and I still got that error message.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when [installing Jekyll and Ruby in the Windows 10 Bash Linux Subsystem](https://andydunkel.net/windows/software/2017/06/05/jekyll_windows_bash.html). It turned out, that the development package from Ruby was missing. I had to install it first:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.4-dev
```

In my case. Try to install the dev package in Cygwin package manager, in your case its version 2.3.

Andy

Comment: I decided to use Windows Subsystem for Linux to get Jekyll working. That said, I will use Cygwin to provide a "Unixy" way of running my Windows commands and use WSL when Cygwin cannot get the job done.

Comment: Just FYI. I did add ruby-devel. Different error. Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
    current directory: /cygdrive/c/Users/myuser/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
/usr/bin/ruby.exe -I /usr/share/rubygems -r ./siteconf20220208-999-90vnq7.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lcrypto... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I encountered the same problem Michael did, and installing the `ruby-devel` package (using the Cygwin Setup installer) solved my problem. A missing `*-devel` Cygwin package is a common cause of errors about missing header files.